# How to create sockaddr from sockaddr_in / sockaddr_in6 structure

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Below is an extract of example code for IPv6 and IPv4 clinet code:

**IPv6**

```
int s;
struct sockaddr_in6 addr;

s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
addr.sin6_port = htons(5000);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &addr.sin6_addr);
connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

**IPv4**

```
int s;
struct sockaddr_in addr;

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

My aim is to write a user defined connect API for both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. Since both of them convert structures to *struct sockaddr* structure - programtically how can we convert the **sockaddr_in** and **sockaddr_in6** to **sockaddr** structure (populate its member variables) and then call connect with sockaddr sturcure?

Comment: I suspect, with `memcpy(&addr, &addr_in, sizeof(struct sockaddr)`.

Comment: Use `getaddrinfo()` for populating socket address structures in a protocol-independent way.

Comment: "*connect API*" what do you plan to pass to this API?

Comment: Thanks how can getaddrinfo() API be used to populate structures in a protocol-independent way?

Comment: "*how can ....*" : you might like to have look [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html).

Comment: @alk Though the user defined connect function will take input as ( .. ,struct sockaddr * , ..) but how do we populate sockaddr_in6 and sockaddr_in to sockaddr

Comment: "*how do we populate ...*":  I recommend to have look at the definitions of the various `struct sockaddrXYZ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> programtically how can we convert the `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6` to `sockaddr` structure (populate its member variables) and then call connect with sockaddr structure?

A **typecast** is not a **conversion**.  You are not converting anything.  Just as the examples you provided show, you create a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` instance as needed and then pass it as-is to `connect()`.  You are merely typecasting the *pointer* that points at the struct instance.  Internally, `connect()` will look at its input `addr`'s `sa_family` field and typecast the `addr` back to either `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` accordingly to access the data fields as needed.

> My aim is to write a user defined connect API for both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

If you want to write protocol-agnostic code, you could do something like this:

```
int doConnect(int family, const char *ip, u_short port)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage ss = {};
    socklen_t addrlen;

    switch (family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *) &ss;
            addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
            addr->sin_port = htons(port);
            inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr->sin_addr);
            addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            break;
        }

        case AF_INET6:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *addr = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) &ss;
            addr->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
            addr->sin6_port = htons(port);
            inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip, &addr->sin6_addr);
            addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
            break;
        }

        default:
            return -1;
    }

    int s = socket(family, SOCK_STREAM_IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (s != -1)
    {
        if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &ss, addrlen) < 0)
        {
            close(s);
            s = -1;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

```
int s = doConnect(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", 5000);
```

```
int s = doConnect(AF_INET6, "::1", 5000);
```

However, a better solution is to use `getaddrinfo()` instead and let it allocate the correct `sockaddr` data for you based on the input values it actually parses, eg:

```
int doConnect(const char *ip, u_short port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    struct addrinfo *addr;

    char szPort[6];
    sprintf(szPort, "%hu", port);

    int s = -1;

    int ret = getaddrinfo(ip, szPort, &hints, &addr);
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        s = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
        if (s != -1)
        {
            if (connect(s, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == -1)
            {
                close(s);
                s = -1;
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo(addr);
    }

    return s;
}
```

```
int s = doConnect("127.0.0.1", 5000);
```

```
int s = doConnect("::1", 5000);
```

The nice thing about `getaddrinfo()` is that you can also use it for servers, too.  Simply use the `AI_PASSIVE` flag in the `hints.ai_flags` field, and then use the resulting `addrinfo` item(s) to call `socket()` and `bind()`.

Answer (score -1):

> programtically how can we convert the `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6` to `sockaddr`

You can't, as neither `sockaddr_in` nor `sockaddr_in6` are guaranteed to fit into a `sockaddr` structure.

[A POSIX-compliant system will provide a `sockaddr_storage` type that **is** guaranteed to be large enough to hold any type of `sockaddr` structure](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html):

> The `<sys/socket.h>` header shall define the `sockaddr_storage`
>   structure, which shall be:
>
> - Large enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address structures
> - Aligned at an appropriate boundary so that pointers to it can be cast as pointers to protocol-specific address structures and used to
>     access the fields of those structures without alignment problems
>
> The sockaddr_storage structure shall include at least the following
>   members:
>
> ```
> sa_family_t   ss_family
> ```
>
> When a pointer to a `sockaddr_storage` structure is cast as a pointer
>   to a `sockaddr` structure, the `ss_family` field of the
>   `sockaddr_storage` structure shall map onto the `sa_family` field of
>   the `sockaddr` structure. When a pointer to a `sockaddr_storage`
>   structure is cast as a pointer to a protocol-specific address
>   structure, the `ss_family` field shall map onto a field of that
>   structure that is of type `sa_family_t` and that identifies the
>   protocol's address family.

Comment: Well which is it? It isn't guaranteed or it is?

Comment: @user207421 I wasn't aware that "shall define the `sockaddr_storage` structure, which shall be [l]arge enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address structures" is unclear.